Is finding the CDF from the Laplace transform well-posed?
In my study of Dynamic Light Scattering, I came across the following inverse problem. Let $F(s):[0,T]\rightarrow[0,T]$ be the Laplace transform of a probability distribution $f(t)$ on the real line with finite support. This means that $$F(s)=\int_0^{L}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$ for all $s$, while $$\int_0^{L}f(t)dt=1$$ and $f(t)\geq0$ for all $t\in[0,L]$. The numbers $T$ and $L$ are fixed positive real constants. I found that the inverse problem: obtain $f(t)$ from $F(s)$, is ill-posed. Specifically, we can make a sequence of Laplace transforms $F_n(s)$ converge under the $L_2$ norm to some limiting $F(s)$, while the sequence of PDFs $f_n(t)$ does not converge to $f(t)$. I'll give an example at the end of the question.
However, it seems to be different for the cumulative distribution function. Let the CDF be defined by
$$C(t):= \int_0^t f(t')dt'.$$
The question:
If the Laplace transforms $F_n(s)$ of $f_n(t)$ converge under the $L_2$ norm to the Laplace transform $F(s)$ of $f(t)$, does it follow that the CDFs $C_n(t)$ converge under the $L_2$ norm to $C(t)$?
Own attempts
Both the Laplace transforms $F_n(s)$ and the CDFs $C_n(t)$ are monotone functions. So when we assume smoothness, convergence under the $L_2$ norm is equivalent to pointwise convergence. So the question can be restated as follows: if the Laplace transforms converge pointwise, do the CDFs also converge pointwise?
Finding the PDF is ill-posed: Let $$f_n(t):=\frac{1}{t\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{-(\ln(t)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}(1+\sin(2\pi n(\ln t-\mu)/\sigma)).$$
This is a lognormal distribution multiplied by a sinusoid.
Here we take $\mu$ such that $e^{\mu}$ lies inside $[0,L]$, and we take $\sigma$ very small.
Now $f_n(t)$ is a probability distribution for all $n$ (up to a very small normalizing factor). The Laplace transforms $F_n(s)$ of $f_n(t)$ converge uniformly on $[0,T]$ to the Laplace transform $F(s)$ of the lognormal distribution:
$$f(t):=\frac{1}{t\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{-(\ln(t)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$
However, the PDFs $f_n(t)$ do not converge to $f(t)$ under the $L_2$ norm.
Here is an illustration of $f(t)$ and one instance of $f_n(t)$:


This depends on the assumptions you make on $f_n(t)$: in the beginning you speak about $f(t)$ having finite support -> this is not true for your counterexample with log normal distributions. In general, you need a criterion on the tails of your random variables. Note that that the tail of the log normal distribution decays quite slowly as $t\to \infty$.

Hi David! So in my counterexample, I intended $f_n(t)$ to have finite support. When $\sigma$ is small, more than $99.99%$ of the area under the lognormal distribution is inside of $[0,L]$. So to convert it to an actual probability distribution with finite support, we just need to multiply by a normalizing factor (like 1.0001).

No chance. A simple integration by parts yields a simple relation between the Laplace transforms of C and f, so inverting one is basically as bad as inverting the other.

Thanks for your comment@MichaelRenardy! I thought about this, and the situation for $C$ seems to be much nicer than $f$. The reason is that $C$ is a monotone function (being a CDF). Knowing that the output of the Laplace Inversion is monotone, should make it much more well-behaved.

Your example is essentially an instance of the following phenomenon: convergence in distribution can occur without convergence of density functions

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$

So the question can be restated as follows: if the Laplace transforms converge pointwise, do the CDFs also converge pointwise?

The answer is yes.
Indeed, let $P_n$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$) and $P$ be any probability distributions supported on a finite interval $[a,b]$ such that $LP_n\to LP$ pointwise on an interval $[0,T]$ for some real $T>0$, where $LQ$ is the Laplace transform of a probability distribution $Q$, so that
$$(LQ)(t):=\int e^{-tx}Q(dx)$$
for real $t$.
Take any subsequence $(P_{n_k})$ of the sequence $(P_n)$ that converges weakly to a probability distribution $D$. Since $e^{-tx}$ is continuous in $x$, it follows that $(LP_{n_k})(t)\to (LD)(t)$ for all real $t$. So,
$$LP=LD \text{ on } [0,T]. \tag{10}\label{10}$$
Since the distribution $P$ is supported on a finite interval, it is determined by its moments $m_k(P)$ ($k=1,2,\ldots$) -- see e.g. Theorem 30.1 in Billingsley. But
$$m_k(P)=(-1)^k (LP)^{(k)}(0)$$
for $k=0,1,\dots$, so that the $m_k(P)$'s are in turn determined by the values of $LP$ on $[0,T]$. So, $P$ is determined by the values of $LP$ on $[0,T]$. So, by \eqref{10}, $D=P$. So, any weakly convergent subsequence of the sequence $(P_n)$ weakly converges to $P$.
Also, since all the $P_n$'s are supported on a finite interval, the sequence $(P_n)$ is tight.
So, by the Corollary to Theorem 29.3 on p. 381 in Billingsley's book, $(P_n)$ weakly converges to $P$.
That is, the c.d.f. $C_n$ of $P_n$ converges to the c.d.f. $C$ of $P$ at every point of continuity of $C$.
Finally, if $C$ is absolutely continuous (or just continuous), then $C_n\to C$ pointwise. $\quad\Box$

Thanks for your answer! I get a bit lost where you say 'so, inversing the Laplace transform,'. Why can we do this for $f_{n,\epsilon}$ while it is not allowed for $f_n$?

@Riemann: Because $L(f_{n,\epsilon})(s+it)$ for real $s,t$ decreases (very) fast in $|t|$, whereas in general we cannot say this concerning $L(f_{n})(s+it)$.

Ok I checked and $|L(f_n)(s+it)|\leq1$ for all s and t, while $|L(\psi_{\epsilon})(s+it)|=e^{0.5s^2\epsilon^2-0.5t^2\epsilon^2}$ which is $O(e^{-0.5t^2\epsilon^2})$.

So we can use Mellin's inverse formula and Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to prove that $f_{n,\epsilon} \rightarrow f_{\epsilon}$.

However, there is one thing remaining to verify. We know that $L(f_{n,\epsilon})(s)$ converges to $L(f_{\epsilon})(s)$ on real inputs $s\in [0,T]$. Why does it follow that the same holds for complex inputs $s+it$?

@Riemann : The standard definition of the Laplace transform is for all complex arguments $s$ with $\Re s>0$. Your definition, which I noticed only now, is very strange, for two additional reasons: (i) your "Laplace transform" is defined only on a finite interval and (ii) the co-domain must be the same as the domain. Do you want to say anything about this?

@Riemann : I have now presented a different kind of argument, for the same "yes" answer.

You're right, what I called the 'Laplace transform' is actually a restriction of the Laplace transform to a finite real interval. I should have emphasized this in my question. The reason for using this particular definition is that in Dynamic Light Scattering, we can only measure the Laplace transform for real inputs.

Thank you so much!
